# Paralleization for nested loops

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing, apply

Thanks in advance.

I have a three nested for loops, the lowest of which contains a conditional if statement evaluation.

The code runs successfully, albeit very slowly using 1 foreach loop and 2 nested for loops. For my 'real' data, I can run ~ **1000** x **2000** x **160** iterations in about 16 hours. I want to scale this is to ~ **10000** x **2000** x **160**, which will take way too long to run (>100 hours). Ideally I'd like to transform the nested for loops for apply loops as I'm aware they run much faster. I've constructed sample code as follows:

```
library("foreach") 
library("doMC") 
registerDoMC()

R = 10
N = 5
M = 10

data_matrix <- matrix(data=runif(50,N,M),ncol=10)

cos_function<- function(x,y){
  res<-runif(1,3,5)
  res<-res + (3/x) + (4/y)
  return(res)
}


results<-foreach(k=1:R,combine=rbind) %dopar% {
  dummy<-matrix(0, N, M)
    for (i in 1:N) {
      for (j in 1:M) {
        if (cos_function(i, j)  <= data_matrix[i,j]) {
          dummy[i,j] = 1
              }
        }
  return(dummy)
}
```

I am having a lot of trouble coming up with ways to expedite this process: i.e. including parallelization of the nested loops, switching to nested apply functions, combining the nested loops into an apply loop. As you can probably tell, I am very new to R and parallelization, so any guidance would be extremely helpful.

Comment: If you scale this problem up to 10000 x 2000 x 160, you're going to run into some serious memory challenges. I'm not even sure it's possible to create a matrix that large in R, even if you have enough memory in your computer.

Answer (score 1):

I know your data are only toy data and this answer does not answer your original question, but did you consider to optimize your matrix calculation?

The following code runs on my laptop in ~ 90 sec (instead of 16h):

```
R <- 160
N <- 1000
M <- 2000

## construct your data_matrix and replicate it R-times to get the same size
## like the cosmatrix
data_matrix <- matrix(data=rep(runif(N*M, N, M), R), byrow=TRUE, ncol=M)

## construct whole cosmatrix (inclusive replications R)
cosmatrix <- matrix(data=runif(N*M*R, 3, 5), ncol=M)

## perform your cos_fun
cosmatrix <- t(t(cosmatrix+3/(1:N)) + 4/(1:M))

## comparison
cosmatrix <= data_matrix
```

Comment: hi @sgibb, thanks for your answer. I'm sorry I didn't specify that the top level loop (R= 1000, or 10,000) has to be the top loop because the function basically shuffles the data R times. Also I should have mentioned that the toy data probably would run much quicker than 16 hours :)

Comment: @ben Ok, but the last two lines (`cosmatrix <- t(t(cosmatrix+3/(1:N)) + 4/(1:M))` and `cosmatrix <= data_matrix`) could avoid your inner loop (simply remove the `R` in the matrix creation process).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very familiar with parallelization, but perhaps changing the following will be faster

```
dat<- matrix(data=runif(50,N,M),ncol=10)
#defining a new version of cos which takes a matrix
new_cos<-function(m) (3/m$i) + (4/m$j)
#create a data.frame ij which holds i and j combinations as each row.
ij<-expand.grid(i=seq(N),j=seq(M))
#now use this for your res. This will return a vector, where res[1] is the result of i=1 and j=1,
#res[2] is the result of i=2, j=1.
res<-runif(M*N,3,5)+new_cos(ij)
##now this will compare as appropriate, since the comparisons will be done column-wise along dat
##multiply booleans by 1 to get your 1/0 matrix
1*(res<=dat)
```